# Accessor that decrypts model value isn't working

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-6, accessor

I have a trait that uses accessors and mutators to encrypt model values:

```
trait Encryptable
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
            return $value;
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

**Comments Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['content','user_id','commentable_id', 'commentable_type'];
protected $encryptable = [
    'content'
];
```

**CommentController**

```
public function storePostComment(Request $request, Post $Post)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    $comment = $post->comments()->create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'content' => $request->content
    ]);
    
    
    dd($comment->content);
    //return new CommentResource($comment);
}
```

What's happening is that when I pass the `return new CommentResource($comment);` gives me the comments content encrypted, but `dd($comment->content);` decrypts the comments content. How do I decrypt the entire comment object so I can output it in a resource?

**Edit For CommentResource**

```
class CommentResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'content' => $this->content,
            'owner' => $this->owner,
        ];
    }
}
```

**Edit 2 for answer**

Here's my attempt:

```
use App\Comment;

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CommentResource extends JsonResource
{
    
    public function __construct(Comment $resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
    
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'content' => $this->content,
            'owner' => $this->owner,
        ];
    }
}
```

Error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Resources\CommentResource::__construct() must be an instance of App\Http\Resources\Comment, instance of App\Comment given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-app/app/Http/Controllers/Api/CommentController.php on line 31

## Edit 3 (final edit)

Here's what I figured out:

I tried a bunch of various combinations along with @Edwin Krause answer. I have another model using this encryptable trait and outputting in a resource that works fine.

To give a bit more context to this question I found out there was a problem using assertJsonFragment in a test:

**CommentsTest**

```
/* @test **/
public function a_user_can_comment_on_a_post()
{
    $decryptedComment = ['content'=>'A new content']
    $response = $this->json('POST',  '/api/comment/' . $post->id, $decryptedComment);

        $response->assertStatus(201);

        $response->assertJsonStructure([
            'data' => [
                'owner',
                'content'
            ]
        ])
        ->assertJsonFragment(['content' => $decryptedContent['content']]);
}
```

`assertJsonFragment` was returning the encrypted content and therefore failing because it was being tested against the decrypted comments content.

I used `dd(new CommentResource($comment));` in the controller to check to see if it the content was decrypting, it wasn't.

I tried various different things trouble shooting with `dd()` in the controller method and even testing in the browser. Still nothing. I added @Edwin Krause code and still nothing on `dd()`

I finally got lucky and got rid of dd() with @Edwin Krause and changing my controller to:

**Working code combined with @Edwin Krause answer in my CommentResource**

```
$comment = Comment::create([
    'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
    'content' => $request->content,
    'commentable_type' => 'App\Post',
    'commentable_id' => $post->id,
]);

return new CommentResource($comment);
```

The tests went green. I tried `dd(new CommentResource($comment));` and the content was encrypted still. The content output on the broweser and `assertJsonFragment` worked. I must've tried so many combinations to try and figure this out and I kind of just got lucky.

I'm unsure as to why this is the way it is, but I've already spent hours on this, so I can't troubleshoot why it's breaking. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: Can you share your `CommentResource` code?

Comment: @apokryfos, just shared it in the edit

Comment: I get the same error when adding the use statement before the namespace

Comment: There’s no need to override the constructor of the resource class. Just access the properties and methods of the model by using `$this->resource->content` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion to try and override the constructor of the JsonResource and typecast the $resource parameter to your Modelclass.
It work's for other things, not sure if it fixes your issue, that needs to be tested

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use App\Comment;

class CommentResource extends JsonResource
{

  public function __construct(Comment $resource)
  {
    $this->resource = $resource;
    $this->resource->content = $resource->content;
  }

  ....
```

**Edit:**
I Played around a bit more with the constructor and the modified version should actually work. I don't have any encrypted data to play with, but logically this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is what I got:

>Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Resources\CommentResource::__construct() must be an instance of App\Http\Resources\Comment, instance of App\Comment given

Comment: Dont' forget the `use App\Comment;` statement, if that's where your Model is located

Comment: Your use statement should be below the namespace

Comment: Thanks, that removed the error, but unfortunately my content is still not decrypting.

Comment: Hey, I edited my question. I got the answer, but I'm not sure as to what is going on. I think you had a part to play in it. If you know what happen and want to edit your answer I'll be sure to mark your answer as correct. Please alert me when you've changed your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, also not sure. And unfortunately unable to reproduce as I don't have any project at thee moment that uses encrypted fields. I'm glad you got it working though...